# FCM doesn't work when my App is in "App Standby mode"

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, sendbird, android-appstandby

I'm building an Android App that implements a chat using the Sendbird service.
Sendbird uses the FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to send the notifications of a new messages received when the App is in background.

All works fine if the Android Energy Saving is disabled, but if this is active, I don't receive notification for some messages.

If I put my App in background and set it in "AppStandby mode" as suggested in Android Developer page ( https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby ), I saw that FCM doesn't work and my notifications messages are lost.

I used the following shell commands:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
$ adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> true
```

Instead all works fine when my App is in "Doze mode".

Because it's the Sendbird server that send to my App the notifications, by FCM, I can't set High priority of messages and I also think that High Priority is not the correct way to solve the problem.

Anyone has an idea for solve the problem? Help me please!!!!

Comment: In sendbird the users can receive push notifications after their app goes into the background or user is in disconnected mode.
If you want notification when app is in foreground or connected mode then you have to generate manually